# Widevine DRM playback on Chromecast

Tags: android, ios, chromecast, drm, widevine

Ive been reading up on getting widevine playback to happen on the chromecast after a device has connected to it. Ive already got widevine working for movie titles in both android and ios and Im not sure where to begin as far as what I should pass as my custom data to the player. Ive had a brief look at the sample at

https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM

but I have yet to try to implement it as I dont want to be spinning my wheels trying to pass random keys and things into the receiver. Since I have all the necessary authentications taking place on the device already what would I need to send to the receiver.

Comment: The sample project supports Widevine as well, so you should look at that project.

Comment: @AliNaddaf thanks for commenting on my question. Is it possible to get the drm receiver working for dev purposes if I just host it on google drive for the time being?

Comment: Hosting on Google Drive is fine; we just don't recommend it for production otherwise there is not technical reason to stop you from using it. Instructions are here: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Comment: @AliNaddaf - i am trying to play WV content with this receiver: https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer .. it's working for me with my Player Ready streams but it's not working with the WV streams .. i am trying to understand what parameters i need to send to the receiver in order to play .. for example: licenseCustomData and licenseUrl  is needed in the host ? i need to send only the mediaElement and the url ? right now when i am trying to do that the CC is downloading 1 chunk and fails after 30000ms, and then tries agin to download the same chunk.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but for others that need help, all you really need to do is pass the license url in the custom data.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        jsonObject.put("licenseUrl", licenseUrl);
    } catch (JSONException e){
        Utils.log("Failed to add license to Json object.");
    }

    MediaInfo mediaInfo =
            new MediaInfo.Builder(videoUrl)
                    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                    .setContentType("video/mp4")
                    .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                    .setStreamDuration(currentPosition)
                    .setCustomData(jsonObject)
                    .build();
    return new MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).build();
```

For the receiver, be sure to create a CAF (not a Receiver v2) and refer to this [guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/mpl/streaming_protocols) for the Widevine setup. The server will need to read the license and allow it for Widevine playback using Javascript on the receiving end.